# React best practice for full page componentization or only the parts of the page that need it

Tags: reactjs

Since React became the hottest thing, I've been using it - but my experience with it has been one in which the dev architect implements the pages in the following way. So, given what I show below, I am curious if people are over using React.

1. Basically one html page, and insert 'divs' into the page, normal html.. then our "insertion" page has a bunch of renderDOM's to insert your "new component" into a HTML page that is litered with div id's etc.. But there is literally no content that is NOT derived from react components.
2. Single page app, in which every single ui/view item is a react component. As above, there is no content derived that is not from a react component.

Both of these approaches I've used, the whole page is just a giant react component.. one (#1) has a bunch of divs with ids for renderDOM's, and the other (#2) the whole page and every subsequent page is all react components.

I am curious if this approach degrades and is not scaleable over time because there is literally no rendered HTML outside of our BUILD process... meaning, it is just one giant javascript file.

I could be wrong, but something tells me that the skeleton of the pages should still be HTML, and only those sections of the page that need dynamism should be react components.

Your thoughts? Your implementations?

I have done any isomorphic implementations.

Comment: I'm curious about the 2nd approach of whole page being a component including the root `<html>`. I find this very easily achievable from the server side since it's just a generated string. But how do you deliver the JavaScript bundle to the front-end? There must be at least a very tiny HTML document sent (`<!DOCTYPE html><html><script></script></html>`), isn't it? Or in other words: React full page-component sites aren't possible without server-side rendering I guess.